# Smoothly join two rounded rectangles at one joint

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes, pathfinder

I would like to join my two rounded rectangles together into a single shape at the elbow joint they create but no matter how accurately I line them up, whenever I combine them into a single shape the joint is off and you can tell there is a curve and it's not a single smooth shape.

Is there a way to create this shape in a more precise way?

**Pre-Pathfinder**
[image: Pre-pathfinder]

**Post-Pathfinder**
[image: Post-pathfinder]

Comment: Why not expand a stroke with round csp and joint?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To expand on @joojaa's comment:

**Step 1**
Use the pen tool to create a stroked path in the middle of your graphic, like so:
[image: step1]

**Step 2**
Set the stroke size to match the width of your graphic. Set the cap to "Round Cap" and the corner to "Round Join" for the rounded look you're after
[image: stroke]

Almost there:
[image: almost there]

**Step 3**
Expand the shape
[image: expand]
[image: accept]

We got the correct shape:
[image: correct]

**Final Step**
Stroke it like you mean it. I gave it an inner stroke of 5px, and voila:
[image: success]

Answer (score -2):

Open Corel Draw:

Step 1
Create two intersecting rounded rectangles - intersecting at the curves.Then press shift key and select Both the shapes.

Step 2
Once both the shapes are selected click on 'Weild' which is on the top toolbar. This will merge both the shapes

Step 3
As you see the curve is still uneven, select the shape tool (F10) from the toolbar

[image]

Step 4
After clicking on the shape tool you will see 2-3 nodes on the line. I would suggest to remove those nodes which are on the curve as this will give you a perfect curve.
Or you can click on the blue arrows and adjust it untill you get a perfect curve

Step 5
If the nodes at the curves are deleted you get this result

[image]

Comment: The question is about Adobe Illustrator, not CorelDraw.